# amsmath's multline and fleqn

Tags: equations, amsmath, multline

As a `fleqn` fanatic, I run across this problem once every week: when splitting a long formula using amsmath's `multline`, the middle lines are flushed left:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
  1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12 \\
  +13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21+22 \\
  +23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

While this is even documented, I think it is rather borken behaviour.

Is there a way to *fix* this? I understand that `amsmath` is essentially frozen, but even some kludgy way, even a `\shovecenter` that could eventually become part of the thankfully more lively `mathtools` would be helpful!

**P.S.** This fundamentalistic adherence of `multline` to the `fleqn` option is to be contrasted with the more liberal approach taken by `gathered`, by the way! The worst of both worlds :-)

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \[
    \left(
      \begin{gathered}
        1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12 \\
        16+17+18+19+20+21+22 \\
        +23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31
      \end{gathered} 
    \right)
  \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: (Anyone knows who named the beast `multline`? I've always wondered why it is not `multiline`...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this is a kludge, but you can take advantage of the `\multline` `\shoveright` feature
to reposition lines that are erroneously positioned too far to the left:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
  1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12 \\
  \shoveright{+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21+22} \kern.1\textwidth \\
  +23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

[image: outpot of example code]

the amount of extra space needed at the end of such a line is (unfortunately) a
matter for experimentation.

the positioning bug was reported long ago (in 1996), and a fix is known, but
updates to `amsmath` haven't been scheduled.

in answer to the question posed in a comment as to who gave this beast the name
`multline`, that was michael spivak; the concept, and a good part of the code, were
lifted from the original `amstex` (non-latex!) package.

Comment: Ah! For some reason I imagined \shoveright would ignore any spacing after it in the like. Thanks!

Comment: Barbara, when you're saying a fix is known, is this maybe a fix one could apply to one's own documents by patching amsmath? I'm currently writing my thesis and fixing all `multline` environments manually takes a lot of time.

Comment: @sebhofer -- on reviewing our internal notes, i find that the "fix" i mentioned is simply a workaround, not a correction in the code.  so a patch hasn't been worked out.  sorry to report no help here.

Answer (score 6):

Just add `\hfill` as needed to the middle lines. With three lines:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
  1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12 \\
\hfill  +13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21+22 \hfill\\
  +23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With four lines:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
  1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12 \\
\hfill  +13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21+22 \hfill\hfill\\
 \hfill\hfill +23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31+32 \hfill\\
+33+34+35+36+37+38+39+40+41
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Indeed, if the length of the lines is very different, you might have to add some extra spacing besides the `\hfill`