# Disable fleqn option for multline environments?

Tags: equations, amsmath, multline

Getting into the same trouble as in [amsmath's multline and fleqn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/234074/18401), I wonder if it is possible to enable `amsmath`'s `fleqn` option (globally, no other choice) but disable it for `multline` environment (okay, that's not ideal but, anyway)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internally, the `fleqn` option sets a flag `\if@fleqn` so all that you need to do is turn this off. The simplest way to do this is using the `\preto` command from the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\preto\multline{\@fleqnfalse}% disable fleqn inside multline environments
\makeatother

\begin{document}

  \begin{multline}
    1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12 \\
    +13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21+22 \\
    +23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31
  \end{multline}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

A second option would be to define a general environment, called `nofleqn` below, that allows you to turn off `fleqn` whenever you wanted. The way this environment works is that it takes one argument, which is the name of the environment that you really want to use (such as `multine`, `align`, `align*`, etc) and then you add the contents of the environment as usual. Using the code, which uses the [environ](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/environ) package, the MWE below produces:

[image]

For reference, an undoctored `multline` environment is also given. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{environ}
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{nofleqn}[1]{\@fleqnfalse\begin{#1}\BODY\end{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

  Without fleqn:
  \begin{nofleqn}{multline}
    1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12 \\
    +13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21+22 \\
    +23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31
  \end{nofleqn}

  With fleqn:
  \begin{multline}
    1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12 \\
    +13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21+22 \\
    +23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31
  \end{multline}

\end{document}
```

Of course, you could define a fleqn-less version of the `multline` environment in exactly the same way. In fact, if you know the name of the environment that you are using then you don't need `environ`:

```
\newenvironment{Multline}{\@fleqnfalse\multline}{\endmultline}
```

In all cases it is necessary to enclose the defining code in `\makeatletter....\makeatother` because otherwise LaTeX will complain about ythe `@` in `\if@fleqn`. I think that this should work without issues but I have not tested it thoroughly so there may be unintended side-effects.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a redefinition of the `multline` and `multline*` environments where lines after the first are indented twice the `\mathindent` (you can easily spot where to act if you prefer a different spacing).

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse,environ}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% save the original environments
\cs_set_eq:NN \db_multline_start: \multline
\cs_set_eq:NN \db_multline_end: \endmultline
\cs_set_eq:Nc \db_multline_star_start: {multline*}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{amsmathmultline}{}
  {\db_multline_start:}
  {\db_multline_end:}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{amsmathmultline*}{}
  {\db_multline_star_start:}
  {\db_multline_end:}

% redefine them
\RenewEnviron{multline}
 {
  \db_multline:nV {multline} \BODY
 }
\RenewEnviron{multline*}
 {
  \db_multline:nV {multline*} \BODY
 }
\seq_new:N \l_db_multline_seq
\cs_new_protected:Nn \db_multline:nn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_db_multline_seq { \\ } { #2 }
  \begin{amsmath#1}
  \seq_use:Nn \l_db_multline_seq { \multlineaddspace } \hfill
  \end{amsmath#1}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \db_multline:nn { nV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\multlineaddspace}{o}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{\\[#1]}{\\}\hspace{\mathindent}%
}


\begin{document}

\lipsum*[3]
\begin{multline}
  1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12 \\[2ex]
  +13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21+22 \\[2ex]
  +23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31
\end{multline}
\lipsum*[4]
\begin{multline*}
  1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12 \\
  +13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21+22 \\
  +23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31
\end{multline*}
\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice indeed: the indentation of the first line is then the same as in the other display math environments. The only drawback is, the last line has the same indentation as the other ones (but the 1st one) and, in order to mimic the default `multline` environment, it could be nice to make it have a bigger indentation (say triple `\mathindent`).

Comment: Okay, just a matter of `\seq_use:Nnnn \l_db_multline_seq { \\ \hspace{\mathindent} } { \\ \hspace{\mathindent} } { \\ \hspace{2\mathindent} }  \hfill` instead of `\seq_use:Nn \l_db_multline_seq { \\ \hspace{\mathindent} } \hfill`.

Comment: I'll accept the Andrew's answer instead of yours because it answers exactly my question. But I badly didn't ask exactly what I want, and you read my mind: your solution is in fact I was looking for :)

Comment: Sigh, your code isn't compatible with the optional argument of  `\\ `, e.g. `\\[1cm]`. Do you see a workaround?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Yes, it's possible! `;-)` Updated version is online.

Comment: Very nice! Is there any reason for creating `\multlineaddspace` as a document level command?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé It should have an optional argument, whereas `expl3` level commands haven't one.

Comment: Wouldn't be better for `expl3` to provide commands with optional argument(s)?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé They're at different levels and, no, it won't happen.