# Why a patch that works for align environment doesn't work for flalign environment?

Tags: align, amsmath, alignat, patching

I'm trying to [Add a marginal note when a page break occurs in the middle of a multi-line equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/396833/18401), using the nice method provided by egreg in [its answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/398268/18401) to my question: [Disable fleqn option for multline environments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/398116/18401)

Since page breaks may occur in the middle of both `align` and `flalign` environments, I'm trying to patch both of them in the spirit of the minimized example below (which has the nice feature to add "foo" and "bar" respectively before and after each `\\` encountered in these environments).

The problem is, this patch works nicely for `align` but fails for `flalign`: as soon as the latter is uncommented in the document body, the compilation fails with the error:

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.78 \end{flalign}
```

*and this happens even if `flalign` isn't patched*, i.e. if :

```
\clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {align,flalign}
```

is replaced by :

```
\clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {align}
```

Do you see what's going on and how to make this patch working for `flalign` as well? (The same question could be asked for `alignat`.)

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse,environ}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter

\clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {align,flalign}
\clist_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {
  % save the original environments
  \cs_set_eq:cc {db_#1_start:} {#1}
  \cs_set_eq:cc {db_#1_end:} {end#1}
  \cs_set_eq:cc {db_#1_star_start:} {#1*}
  \NewDocumentEnvironment{amsmath#1}{}
  {\cs:w db_#1_start:\cs_end:}
  {\cs:w db_#1_end:\cs_end:}
  \NewDocumentEnvironment{amsmath#1*}{}
  {\cs:w db_#1_star_start:\cs_end:}
  {\cs:w db_#1_end:\cs_end:}
  \RenewEnviron{#1}
  {
    \cs:w db_patch:nV\cs_end: {#1} \BODY
  }
  \RenewEnviron{#1*}
  {
    \cs:w db_patch:nV\cs_end: {#1*} \BODY
  }
}
% redefine them
\seq_new:N \l_db_patch_seq
\cs_new_protected:Nn \db_patch:nn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_db_patch_seq { \\ } { #2 }
  \begin{amsmath#1}
    \seq_use:Nn \l_db_patch_seq { \db@patch } \hfill
  \end{amsmath#1}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \db_patch:nn { nV }

\NewDocumentCommand{\db@patch}{so}{%
  \quad\text{foo}
  \IfValueTF{#2}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\\*[#2]}{\\[#2]}%
  }{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\\*}{\\}
  }%
  \text{bar}\quad
}

\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  1 + 1 & = 2 \\
  2 + 1 & = 3 \\
  3 + 1 & = 4 \\
  4 + 1 & = 5 \\
  5 + 1 & = 6 \\
  6 + 1 & = 7 \\
  7 + 1 & = 8 \\
  8 + 1 & = 9 \\
  9 + 1 & = 10
\end{align}

% \begin{flalign}
%   1 + 1 & = 2 \\
%   2 + 1 & = 3 \\
%   3 + 1 & = 4 \\
%   4 + 1 & = 5 \\
%   5 + 1 & = 6 \\
%   6 + 1 & = 7 \\
%   7 + 1 & = 8 \\
%   8 + 1 & = 9 \\
%   9 + 1 & = 10
% \end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use `flalign`, it's easier.

Comment: @egreg This patch is supposed to be part of a class, the users of which a priori allowed to use `flalign`. Admittedly, I could refrain them to use it by redefining it to `\relax` with an error message advising to just use `align` instead; but, even this, I can't do it AFAICS.

Comment: I managed to redefine `flalign` to `\relax` (with an error message advising to just use `align` instead) but I would prefer to patch it just like I could patch `align`.

Comment: You could just set `flalign` equal to `align` and issue a warning message. If this is a house style, imposing that style is what the class is meant to do.

Comment: @cfr That's what's I did as a workaround and, indeed, that's what I'd like for the house style. For `alignat`, though, it could be reasonable to let the users still use its features.

Comment: I think the issue is because you're redefining the end of `align`, and `flalign` uses `\endalign` internally to end it. I'm working out a better way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that when you redefine `align`, that redefines the command `\endalign`, which (if you check out the source for amsmath) is used as the end of all the alignment environments.

A solution would be to patch it in a different manner, as follows:

```
\usepackage{xparse,etoolbox}

%Beggining Same as in the question
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {flalign,align}
\clist_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {
%We use collect@body, which is what's used internally by NewEnviron
%It takes in the environment body, and then calls the next cs
  \AtBeginEnvironment{#1}{\collect@body\db_patch:n}
}
% redefine them
\seq_new:N
\l_db_patch_seq
\cs_new_protected:Nn
\db_patch:n
{
  \seq_set_split:Nnn
  \l_db_patch_seq {
  \\ } { #1 }
    \seq_use:Nn
    \l_db_patch_seq
    { \db@patch
    } 
}
%The remainder as in the question
```

Here, we only patch the beggining of the environments, using old fashioned tools from `etoolbox`, avoiding redefining the `\endalign`.

It's also worth noting that you don't need the `environ` package, because amsmath also defines the `\collect@body` command which we use to read in the environment.

Comment: Sigh... shame on me! Is it possible to re-offer a bounty?

Comment: Think so. Might cost you double, though.

Comment: Bounty re-offered! :)